# Insert field value into DB without node_save

Tags: 7, entities

I need to insert +30.000 field values in one of my client site for 1 content type only. I can not use the standard way (node_load, change, node_save) because when I save node this start a series of events and actions.

So, can I insert my values directly to the db table ? Or is there an other way ?

M.

Comment: I think we have a duplicate of this if you search for "field_attach_update"